# Any smart JSON/JS Object counting packages?

Tags: json, node.js

I don't mean to be duplicating any questions, since I have read so many great answers here on StackOverflow.

Given the below JSON data:

```
[
  {
    “department”: “vice”,
    “team”: [
      {
        "selected": "Yes"
      },
      {
        “selected": “No”
      }
    ],
    “fund”: [
      “team_a”
      “team_c”
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to return a count of selected, so from the above `'yes'=1` and `'no'=1`.
I understand I can do it through `for` loop, using a simple `countYes++` to return the answer, however I have 2 questions as below:

- Is there any other way (i.e. using some npm package).
- In my example the options are simple Yes and No, if I have a bigger list of things to count, how to count all unique ones > 0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write using vanilla JS you can look for library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) for more options.

```
var data = [
    {
        "department": "vice",
        "team": [
            {
                "selected": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "selected": "No"
            }
        ],
        "fund": [
            "team_a",
            "team_c"
        ]
    },
    {
        "department": "vice",
        "team": [
            {
                "selected": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "selected": "Yes"
            }
        ],
        "fund": [
            "team_a",
            "team_c"
        ]
    },
    {
        "department": "vice",
        "team": [
            {
                "selected": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "selected": "No"
            }
        ],
        "fund": [
            "team_a",
            "team_c"
        ]
    }
];
function decisionReducer(prev, next) {
    var team = next.team;
    if (team && Array.isArray(team)) {
        team.forEach(function (row) {
            if (row.selected === 'Yes') {
                prev.yes += 1;
            }
            if (row.selected === 'No') {
                prev.no += 1;
            }
        })
    }
    return prev;
};
var counter = data.reduce(decisionReducer, {yes: 0, no: 0})
console.log(counter);
```